# Firebase once("value") trigger both "then" and "catch"

Tags: angular, firebase

Was wondering, I have two functions, one is being loaded by the other.

For error handling, I'm using `then` and `catch` for both of them. the `then` and `catch` for function `A()` is working fine, but the `then` and `catch` for function `B()` - both of `then` & `catch` are being triggered, so I can't place the right message.

```
A() {
    if ( this.page_id ) {
        this.fireDB.database.ref(`/pages/${page_id}`).once("value").then(snapshot => {
            this.Page = snapshot.toJSON();
            console.log(this.CTRL, "[VALID] Page.id:", this.Page.id);

            // Load item's details in page
            this.B();

        }).catch(() => {
            console.log(this.CTRL, "[FAILED] Page ID not found");
            this.has_errors = true;
            this.error_image = "Page could not be found";
        });
    }
}


B() {
    if ( this.page_id && this.item_id ) {
        this.fireDB.database.ref(`/items/${page_id}/${item_id}`).once("value").then(snapshot => {
            console.log("snapshot:", snapshot.val()); // Console log DOES show this row for some reason, value == null
            this.Item = snapshot.val();             // This throw an error that Item is now null, so the template fails

            # This row will never reach ( here, we jump to the `catch` )
            console.log(this.CTRL, "[VALID] Item.id:", this.Item.id);

        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(this.CTRL, "[FAILED] Item ID not found error:", error);
            this.has_errors = true;
            this.error_image = "Item could not be found";
        })
    }
}
```

#### console.log output

```
[PageComponent] Requesting id: -Uyw0OY
[PageComponent] [VALID] Page.id: -Uyw0OY
snapshot: null                             <== Why I'm here ?
[ItemComponent] [FAILED] Item ID not found error: TypeError: "_this.Item is null"
```

So I'm trying to develop the scenario incase 1: page ID is invalid, 2: Item ID is invalid - I want to place a proper msg.

But I'm not sure why it works fine in function `A()` and for function `B()` I need to add an `if ( snapshot.val() !== null )` ?

why I can't just trust the `catch` ?

Why it enters the `.then` even though there's no answer/item in the path requested for function `B()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is totally expected.  When you try to log `this.Item.id`, it will throw an error because `this.Item` is null (assigned from the null `snapshot.val()` that you saw a few lines earlier).  It's an error to reference a property on a null object - the following error message is telling you exactly that: "_this.Item is null".  This error will trigger the following catch, where you are printing it out.

Remove this log line, and you'll see that the catch doesn't get triggered, because you removed the source of the error:

```
console.log(this.CTRL, "[VALID] Item.id:", this.Item.id);
```

Comment: you right, so my 3rd question was, why - if there's no `item_id` - I'm getting in the `then` ? while in `A()` - if the `ID` isn't found - it moves to the `catch` ? or, are you familiar with other way of testing if there's a value or not ?

Comment: Because the location of your query contained no data.  What's what it means when val() returns null.  A and B are querying different locations, and it's not an error to query a location with no data.

Comment: I'll explain, when I test `A()` with an "not found" path ( to test what happens ) - it moves to the `catch` *w/o printing to console.log any msg*, but why `B()` doesn't behave the same when I give it a "not found" path ?

Comment: Sounds like you now have a different problem.  Impossible to say without knowing exactly what you're passing, and the error object passed to the catch block (which you are omitting in your code).

Comment: my bad, found my issue, actually both behave the same, only assiging in `A()` the `this.Page = snapshot.toJSON();` ( which triggered the `catch` not Firebase - not finding the path ) - and doesn't really affect the app if it returns `null` because the template just check `*ngIf="Page"`, while `B()`'s assignment does affects the template, this is why I thought they don't behave the same, thanks again !